# Solving $\sin^3(x) = \sin(A - x) \sin(B - x) \sin(C - x) $ where $A,B,C$ are the angles of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, rotations

**Context:**  While trying to solve for the center of rotation and rotation angle of a uniformly scaled and rotated triangle that will touch the sides of a given $\triangle ABC$ as shown in the figure below, I came across the following trigonometric equation for the angle $\phi$ that the line segments joining the center of rotation with the vertices make with the respective sides:

$\sin^3(\phi) = \sin(A - \phi) \sin(B - \phi) \sin(C - \phi) $

where $A,B,C$ are the vertex angles of $\triangle ABC$.

Short of an analytic solution, I resorted to Newton's method to obtain a numerical solution.  A very accurate solution was obtained in just $2$ iterations.

I was wondering if there is an analytic solution to this equation.  I am aware that one could use the substitution $u = \tan \dfrac{\phi}{2}$ and end up with a polynomial in $u$ of degree $6$, but other than that, is there any other way ?

[image]

Comment: We have an explicit expression for [*Brocard angle*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardAngle.html) namely, $$\cot \omega=\cot A+\cot B+\cot C$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  This indeed gives the angle $\phi = \tan^{-1} (\dfrac{1}{\cot A + \cot B + \cot C }) $

Comment: Yes.  This is exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you very much for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to obtain $x$ solution of the equation
$$\sin^3(x) - \sin(A - x) \sin(B - x) \sin(C - x)=0$$

Let $C=\pi-(A+B)$ and $t=\sin(x)$. Replace and expand the sines to obtain
$$\big[3-2 \cos (A) \cos (A+2 B)-\cos (2 A) \big]t=4  \sin (A) \sin (B) \sin (A+B)\sqrt{1-t^2}$$
$$\tan(x)=\frac t{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{4  \sin (A) \sin (B) \sin (A+B) } { 3-2 \cos (A) \cos (A+2 B)-\cos (2 A)}$$

Comment: Yes.  I've verified your solution numerically and it does give the correct value for $x$.